# How to make part of a function only execute once until it's allowed to do otherwise

Tags: javascript, function

How can I call a javascript function (`repeatedFunction()`) repeatedly but make it so that, let's say an `alert("This function is being executed for the first time")`, is only activated the first time that `repeatedFunction()` is, but the `//other code` is always activated? And also, how can I make the `alert()` allowed to be activated for one more time, like if the `repeatedFunction()` was being executed for the first time again?

Comment: To repeat a function, you can always have `setInterval(myFunction, milliseconds);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Functions are objects. You can set (and later clear) a flag on the function if you like:

```
function repeatedFunction() {
    if (!repeatedFunction.suppress) {
        alert("This function is being executed for the first time");
        repeatedFunction.suppress = true;
    }
    // ...other code here...
}
```

When you want to reset that, any code with access to `repeatedFunction` can clear the `repeatedFunction.suppress` flag:

```
repeatedFunction.suppress = false;
```

The flag doesn't *have* to be on the function, of course, you could use a separate variable.

---

**That said**, I would suggest looking at the larger picture and examining whether the alert in question should really be part of the function at all.

Comment: Your solution seems to be the one that most fits my problem! Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

You can set a flag. Say for example, you have this following code:

```
var flagAlertExecd = false;
function repeatThis () {
  if (!flagAlertExecd) {
    alert("Only once...");
    flagAlertExecd = true;
  }
  // Repeating code.
}
```

And to repeat this code, it is good to use `setInterval`.

```
setInterval(repeatThis, 1000);
```

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript [closure approach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) will fit in this task. It has no global variables, and keeps your task in a single function.

```js
var closureFunc = function(){
    var numberOfCalls = 0;
    return function(){
        if(numberOfCalls===0)
        {
            console.log('first run');
        }
        numberOfCalls++;  

        console.log(numberOfCalls);
    };
};

var a = closureFunc(); //0
a(); //1
a(); //2
var a = closureFunc(); //drop numberOfCalls to 0
a(); //1
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hmkuchhn/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by declaring a variable and incrementing it in your function. Using an `if` statement, you can check how many times it has been triggered. Code :

```
var count = 0;

function myfunc(){
 if(count==0){
    alert("Triggering for the first time");
    count++;
 }
    //Your always triggering code here
 }
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/rimumu/edit?html,js,console,output)

> This even tracks record of the how many times the function is triggered. It can be useful if you don't want to execute the `alert()` on `nth` time.
>
> You can also use boolean values. Like this :

```
var firstTime = true;

function myfunc(){
 if(firstTime){
    alert("Triggering for the first time");
    firstTime = false;
 }
    //Your always triggering code here
 }
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/noxipu/edit?html,js,console,output)

> The second approach will not track the record of how many times the function has been triggered, it will just determine that whether the function is being invoked for the first time or not.
>
> Both the approaches work fine for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var firstTime = true;

 var myFunction = function() {
   if(firstTime) {
     alert("This function is being executed for the first time");
     firstTime=false;
   }else{
    //whatever you want to do...
   }
 }; //firstTime will be true for the first time, after then it will be false
 var milliseconds = 1000;
 setInterval(myFunction, milliseconds);
 //the setInterval means that myFunction is repeated every 1000 milliseconds, ie 1 second.
```

Comment: This will not execute the always executing code, for the first time. Have a look at the question again!!!

Comment: @Arjun I have fixed the mistake